# Not able to connect to postgreSQL database (Timescale Cloud) when using Grafana in Windows

Tags: windows, postgresql, grafana, timescaledb

I have installed **Grafana** 8.4.4. Enterprise in Windows 10 Pro and I am trying to connect to a **Timescale database** (postgreSQL).

First I tried to connect to **Timescale Cloud** (https://portal.timescale.cloud/login), which uses Timescale version 2.6.0.

In Timescale Cloud service page I can see these credentials:

- Host: `<host-string>`
- Port: `10250`
- User: `tsdbadmin`
- Password: `<timescale-cloud-service-password>`
- Service URI: `postgres://tsdbadmin:<timescale-cloud-service-password>@<host-string>:10250/defaultdb?sslmode=require`
- SSL mode: `require`
- Allowed IP addresses: `0.0.0.0/0`
- PostgreSQL version: 14.2

The database name is: `periodic-measurements`

I have also copied the CA Certificate.

In the Timescale Cloud Data Source in Grafana I have the following configurations:

- Host: `<host-string>:10250`
- Database: `periodic-measurements`
- User: `tsdbadmin`
- Password: `<timescale-cloud-service-password>`
- TLS/SSL Mode: `require`
- TLS/SSL Method: `Certificate content`
- CA Cert: `<CA Certificate>`
- Version: `12+`
- TimescaleDB: `enabled`

When clicking Save & Test I get:

> Query data error

Then, I tried to connect to the Timescale database (postgreSQL version 14.2, Timescale version 2.6.0) contained in my **local Linux instance** (Linux Ubuntu 18.04 on VirtualBox on top of my Windows 10).

From my local Linux terminal I get into the database as follows:

`$ psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U db_owner testdb`

by using the password `<timescale-local-password>`.

In my local Linux instance in `/etc/postgresql/14/main/pg_hba.conf` I have the following line:

`# IPv4 local connections:`

`# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD`

`host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            scram-sha-256`

In Virtual Box in Settings > Network, I have selected Bridged Adapter. In Linux, ifconfig gives me the following:

```
enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.30.129  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.30.255
        inet6 fe80::c757:3763:9a7d:e2f1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:d0:6c:9c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 76  bytes 23686 (23.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 119  bytes 13263 (13.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

In the Timescale Local Data Source in Grafana I have the following configurations:

- Host: `192.168.30.129:5432`
- Database: `testdb`
- User: `db_omver`
- Password: `<timescale-local-password>`
- TLS/SSL Mode: `disable`
- Version: `12+`
- TimescaleDB: `enabled`

When clicking Save & Test I get:

> Database Connection OK

Note also that, by using my Grafana installation in my Linux local instance, I can successfully connect to Timescale Cloud.

Any hint what could be wrong in the connection to Timescale Cloud from Windows Grafana?

Thanks,

Bernardo

Comment: First, I'm unsurprised that your local test is failing. Using your public IP is not likely to work for various reasons. Instead switch to bridged-mode networking for your virtual machine. The virtual machine should then be auto-assigned an IP from your local network, which you will be able to find with `ifconfig` in the virtual machine. Use this IP address for the value of `Host`.

I'm having difficulty understanding exactly what is not working with your connection to Timescale Cloud. Do you see a more precise error in the grafana logs?

Comment: @JamesGuthrie Thanks! The connection to my local Linux instance now works (I have edited the original post with the correct IP address). I do now where to find the Grafana logs in Linux but I do not find any more detailed logs in Windows.